# To loop within array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my below code Im am not able to fetch data within array

```
var str = "Service1|USER_ID, Service1|PASSWORD"
var str_array = str.split(',');
console.log(str_array)
for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++)
{
    str_array[i] = str_array[i].split('|');
}
console.log(str_array)
```

This is the response from above code

```
 /*  [ [ 'Service1', 'USER_ID' ],
    [ 'Service1', 'PASSWORD' ] ]*/
```

I want response to be in two different array like below

```
var array1 = ['Service1']
var array2 = ['USER_ID','PASSWORD']
```

Any help on this will be really helpful

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep related data in two different arrays.

Comment: Do you mean you want the result to be something like {service1: ['user_id', 'password']} so you can do a result.service1?

Comment: @Pengtuzi Yes exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Node, [you can do this:](http://jsfiddle.net/hHGQb/1/)

```
var str = "Service1|USER_ID, Service1|PASSWORD";
var result = str.split(',').reduce(function(collected,splitByComma){

  var splitData = splitByComma.split('|');
  var key = splitData[0].replace(/\s+/gi,''); //Might want to improve this "trim"
  var data = splitData[1];


  if(!collected.hasOwnProperty(key)) collected[key] = [];
  collected[key].push(data);

  return collected;
},{});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //{"Service1":["USER_ID","PASSWORD"]} 

//result.Service1[0] == USER_ID
//result.Service1[1] == PASSWORD
```

It's not wise to place stuff in separate places. You could have them under an object key though. If service name is variable, then you could do:

```
var serviceName = "Service1";
result[serviceName][0] == USER_ID
result[serviceName][1] == PASSWORD
```

Comment: How can place the result in two different array as asked in my question [ [ 'Service1', 'USER_ID' ], [ ' Service1', 'PASSWORD' ] ]

Comment: var headerKeys = Object.keys(result);
console.log(headerKeys) //Service1
console.log(result.headerKeys[0]) //undefined
Why im getting undefined?

Comment: @user3180402 At the bottom of my answer, I added that.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a simple Regex solution

```
var res = "Service1|USER_ID, Service1|PASSWORD".split(/[\|,]/g);
var ar1 = [], ar2 = [];
res.forEach(function(em,i){
 if(i%2==0) {
  if(ar1.indexOf(em.trim())<0){
    ar1.push(em.trim());
  }
 } else {
  ar2.push(em.trim());
 }
});
```

//ar1 and ar2 will contain expected results

Answer (score 0):

As I have understand your question, you will want an array associated with each service key, to be able to do
   services.service1 
and get ['username', 'password' ] ?
If so, here's a solution:

```
var str = "Service1|USER_ID, Service1|PASSWORD".replace(', ', ',').split(','), //[ 'Service1|USER_ID', 'Service1|PASSWORD' ]
   out = {};

   str.forEach(function(element){
    var key, value;
    element = element.split('|');
    key = element[0].trim();
    value = element[1].trim();
    out[key] = out[key] || []; // ensures we can push the value into an array
    out[key].push(value);
});

console.log(out); //{ Service1: [ 'USER_ID', 'PASSWORD' ] }
```